# How do I (self) promote a board game?

Tags: game-development, prototyping

I design a board game. It has a Middle Eastern folklore theme.

It’s a casual family board game for 2-6 players.
It takes about 90 minutes for each level to play. There are total 5 levels and more than 25 scenarios.

I have no idea how much paid marketing will really work.

need feedback where and how do I (self) promote to make a reasonable audience?

Comment: Welcome to Board and Card Games Bruhan! Currently your question is a bit broad and likely to be closed, but don't worry with some edits you can narrow down the focus a bit (and allow others to give you better answers). Try including what you have actually tried so far, along with what specifically you are having an issue with (ie. online promotion, or finding people to play your game in person). Also feel free to check out [the tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how to write good questions and answers.

Comment: As mentioned, the question is very broad.  I think you're asking how to move forward from prototype to store shelves?  This is a long process.  See if any of these help: https://www.toyassociation.org/App_Themes/toyassociation_resp/downloads/resources/toy-association-toy-inventor-and-designer-guide.pdf, https://www.bgdf.com/forums/game-creation/publication, https://www.boardgamegeek.com/spsearch.php?objectid=1&objecttype=region&q=marketing&searchauthor=&forumids%5B%5D=13&searchfield=all&displayresults=excerpt&B1=Submit

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want to build up a fan base.  To do that, you could:

- Introduce it at board game meetups and conventions.
- Send print and play files to interested people over the internet.
- Show it off on board game forums.

Once you have a fan base, then it's time to think about options for publishing the game.  I wouldn't recommend spending any money on marketing until you have a publishing route worked out, since you won't have a product to sell yet, and (depending on which way you go) your publisher will probably already have their own marketing ideas and budget.

Comment: thanks Joe for replying, i do not understand "files" you mean to say send prototypes to interested peoples?

Comment: can you please recommend any online forum, where I can easily add or show my board game?

Comment: @BurhanUllah, by sending "print and play files" I mean sending people what they need to print out their own copy of the game and play it.  The big site for boardgame forums is boardgamegeek.com.